# Would you use 'Isn't she dressed pretty?' or 'Isn't she dressed prettily?'

Tags: adverbs

In which sentence is 'pretty' used as an adverb or as an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretty) licenses the use of the flat adverb intercategorial polyseme **pretty**:

> *pretty* [2 of 4] [adverb]...
>
> 2: in a gracefully pleasing manner: prettily
>
> - *pop vocalists who can sing pretty* – Gerald Levitch

Cambridge Dictionary and Collins do not list this usage, though AHD does. [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretty) adds the caveat 'informal', and I'd go with this. The dictionaries that include the flat adverb usage are American, and (I'm a Brit) I'd avoid the usage myself.

I don't think one can reasonably argue for a depictive adjective usage as in

- *Doesn't she look pretty*?

'Isn't she dressed prettily' is standard, using the -ly adverb.

Comment: In general, Americans use flat adverbs a lot more than the British do.

Comment: Doesn't she look pretty? is not spot on? Really? //For many firms, a Covid reckoning is coming, and it won’t look pretty. 
https://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2021/01/10/many-firms-covid-reckoning-coming-wont-look-pretty/

Comment: The perfectly acceptable sentence 'Doesn't she look pretty?' is given as an example of the **depictive adjective** intercategorial polyseme 'pretty', Lambie. 'Doesn't she look pretty/nice/well/ill/angry...?'